# Gnuplot is terminating abnormally

Tags: gnuplot

I am using IVEware within SAS.  When I ask IVEware to produce plots, I get an error message, "gnuplot terminated abnormally".  The IVEware manual says that the path to gnuplot must be in the settings file for IVEware.  I've checked and it is.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

I checked the location of the gnuplot path in the settings folder and it is correct.  Strangely, the plots functioned once but then didn't function again, even with the same input code in Iveware.